# document.cookie doesn't return me specific cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, vbulletin

I am developing a little script,
And if I want it to work I need to get specific cookie: '`bb_sessionhash`'.

this is my code:

```
<script>
alert("The Cookies: " + document.cookie);
</script>
```

when i'm using '`document.cookie`' i can get any cookie that i want except '`bb_sessionhash`'.

(I am using vbulletin 4.2.0 and more other versions)

**How do I get the '`bb_sessionhash`' cookie?**

Comment: Is that a `HTTP-only` cookie? Then you cannot get it from JavaScript.

Comment: It could also be a cookie set for a different domain, subdomain or path. Or maybe it is not yet set at all :).

Comment: Please show us the exact HTTP header which set that cookie.

Comment: i think that this is HTTP-only cookie :/